# Remove Language button from CTRL/ALT/DEL screen

Tags: windows-7, language

I have a Windows 7 PC and it is set up as a "kiosk PC" IE Windows visually hidden. The only part I can't seem to hide is the language button which shows as the PC shuts down. It is the same one that is on the CTRL/ALT/DEL screen

[image]

It seems this button appears when more than one language is installed. If I click the button, this seems to be the case:

[image]

I have gone to Control Panel --> Region and Language but I can't find the reference to United States anywhere and its not showing in the installed languages.

Can anyone advice how I might get rid of this button?
[image]

Comment: I went ahead and cropped the images for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Method #1**

Under **Keyboards and Languages** you have to click **Change Keyboards...**

Then you remove the keyboard you don't wish to use.

**Method #2**

The next thing to try is to open the **Administrative** tab, then in the **Welcome screen and new users accounts** box click **Copy settings...** (*Note, you may need local admin rights to do this.*)

Then, in that same screen, check the boxes for **Welcome screen and system accounts** and **New user accounts**.

Now press OK until you've closed all the dialogs, and restart your computer.

Comment: That's what I did to bring up the third screenshot...

Comment: I've added another possible method.

Comment: Everything was set to UK but I checked the checkboxes anyway...nothing. I'm wondering if there's a registry hack or something maybe.....

Comment: Also did change system locale under non Unicode programs although it was set to UK

Comment: You restarted too?

Comment: Yes. I've done that too